# Force Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody to update in the explorer preview pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

Just after receiving an email I modify the Outlook MailItem with some values for the subject and HTMLBody properties. Later in the explorer when I select it, the HTMLBody which I updated previously just after receiving it, it's not being shown with the content updated in the explorer preview pane. How can I force to Outlook refresh it without saving the Outlook.MailItem?

Answer (score 0):

If the item has not been selected prior to updating `HTMLBody`, selecting it should show the latest data as long as you remember to call `MailItem.Save`.

Or use `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` - it returns `Word.Document` object currently shown in the preview pane, and you can try to modify that instead.

Comment: But I need to refresh the preview area with the updated outlook.MailItem body content without saving it. First I select it in the explorer list and then explorer SelectionChange event is raised and later I update the HTMLBody content.

Comment: Do not modify the `HTMLBody` then - try to work with `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` - it returns `Word.Document` object currently shown in the preview pane.

Comment: but ActiveInLineResponseWordEditor is not only for Word instead of Outlook?

Comment: It is a Word Object Model object exposed by Outlook- Word-light is what Outlook uses to show and edit emails.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to save changes by calling the `Save` method on the item and then changing selected item in the `Explorer` window (see the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property of the `Explorer` class) or just changing the `CurrentFolder` property.

If you don't want to do something like that you may also consider displaying an Outlook form region instead. It can be an adjucent one which adds a bit of information on top of the email on the reading pane or just complete replacement of the view, so you could display your information instead of a particular item's preview. You may find [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) helpful.